# Exclude subdomain from htaccess redirect. But redirect non-www to www and then to https for the main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am a beginner in the htaccess area.

I have the following rules now

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This helps me to achieve the following

```
example.com => https://www.example.com
```

However, i need to exclude the sub domain:

```
subdomain.example.com/myfile.html => http://subdomain.example.com/myfile.html
```

How can i achieve it ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.
NOTE: I tried a few solutions provided. But none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following  rule for http=> https://www

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```